# PEER_ID_INVALID when sending message to new user

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

How i can send message to new user via WTelegramClient?

```
var peer = new InputPeerUser(user.id,user.access_hash);
await _client.SendMessageAsync(peer, "hello");
```

it returns `peer_id_invalid`. Why?

Comment: Are the `user.id` and `user.access_hash` valid?

Comment: User ID is not the same as Peer ID. The object `InputUser` (https://core.telegram.org/type/InputUser) is not the same as `InputPeer` (https://core.telegram.org/type/InputPeer). Peer is from a conversation / channel / group.

Comment: hash:-3709500452336328166 :userid 5286202569
-------------------------------------------
hash:9103130622756797784 :userid 5201338903
-------------------------------------------      

      user is  from  group or channel!

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the user id/access_hash are coming. A user access_hash is valid only on the logged-in account it was retrieved from.

Also, with WTelegramClient, you do not need to build `InputPeerUser` manually, just pass a `User` object where an `InputPeerUser` is expected, and that structure will be created for you implicitly.

So the solution is to fetch the `User` structure you want, using any API calls or Updates monitoring, and use that `User` on your `SendMessageAsync` call.

For more information, [read this FAQ](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/FAQ.md#access-hash)